# How do I find out executions (and respected configurations) of my Maven plugin from a Mojo?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin). The plugin generates Java code from XML Schemas.

Some people configure `maven-jaxb2-plugin` with several executions. In this case, it is important that they specify different output directories. But it's easy to forget.

I would like to add a diagnostic feature that if there's a different execution which outputs to the same directory, the plugin should log a warning.

To do this, I need to find out which other executions of the same plugin/goal exist in the build. How do I achieve this? Is there anything I could inject into my Mojo so that I get access to executions?

Or should I inject the `project` itself and the descend via `project.build.plugins`, find my plugin, get executions etc.?

As a side question if anyone have seen a reference of things you can inject into `Mojo`, I'd really appreciate that, too..

Alternatively I could solve it if there is a way to pass some data from one execution to the other. Then, in the first execution I could put something like "execution with id X generated code into the directory Y". Later, in the execution Z I could check, if any other execution already generated code into the target directory.

**Update** Data can be passed from one `Mojo` to another one via the [plugin context](https://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/ContextEnabled.html), so that part is solved.